# Random Disposed Object Exception when calling a Web Service from iOS device using Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, web-services, xamarin.ios

When calling a web service (via HTTP connection), we randomly get the following exception:

```
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00065] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:946 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:958 
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web.Services/System.Web.Services.Protocols/WebClientProtocol.cs:173 
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web.Services/System.Web.Services.Protocols/HttpWebClientProtocol.cs:171 
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke (System.String method_name, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00078] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Web.Services/System.Web.Services.Protocols/SoapHttpClientProtocol.cs:354 
at HighJump.OmniTech.Common.WebServices.SynchronizationService.PostTransaction (System.String method, System.String data, System.String session, System.String transactionValues) [0x0001e] in /Users/lbmacmini01/Desktop/branches/v3.4/HighJump.OmniTech.Common/Web References/WebServices/Reference.cs:371
```

The PostTransaction is called from a thread like so:

```
using (SynchronizationService sync = new SynchronizationService())
{
    sync.SetCredentals(creds.Server, creds.User, creds.Password);
    sync.PostTransaction(method, data, session, transactionValues);  
}
```

I have only been able to duplicate the issue when connecting directly to our customer's server running "Windows Server 2008 R2". When I connect to my own server, it seems to work fine.

Connecting to the customer's server using our "Windows" application, using the same generated Web Service SoapHttpClientProtocol class and it works fine. I never get the issue.

It seems like it's a combination of the customer's server and the iOS version of our application.

On an iOS device, it seems like the pattern is that the first time the "PostTransaction" method is called it will work, but the second time we get the error above.

I also tried calling 2 "PostTransaction" in a row, in the same "using" block, the first one works, the second one gives the error.

I have tried a lot of things, not sure what to do anymore.

1. Can the "SoapHttpClientProtocol" be used from a Thread without any
   issue in iOS?
2. Is there any issue creating from threads (ie. "new")
   and disposing of the "SynchronizationService" class derived from "SoapHttpClientProtocol" every time we want to call out to the web service?

I just updated to the latest Xcode and Xamarin.
Now the issue always happens when connecting to the customer's server, but not when connecting to my own server.
Anybody have any ideas?